# Python url data extraction with regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'd like to retrieve the content and `href` link from an HTML tag in Python.

I'm a beginner in regex and am able to retrieve the href content in this way:

```
urls = re.findall('<a class="title" href="(.*?)" title', page)
```

When trying to extract tag's content as well, I get nothing.

```
urls = re.findall('<a class="title" href="(.*?)" title>(.*?)</a>', page)
```

How to do it the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing this 'the right way' is to use a HTML parser.

Comment: Did you try using BeautifulSoup?..https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup

Comment: @KamyarGhasemlou it's not because there, it doesn't care about tag's content.

Comment: Is using an html parser feasible for a small snippet like this one ?

Comment: do you mean the url with tag's content?(normally, <a...> is the tag, so I got a bit confused by your answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is use a parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Trying to parse HTML with regexes is hell and you won't get very far before you hit a wall.

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me to get the URLs from heise.de:

```
urls = re.findall('<a .*?href="(.*?)".*?>', page)
```

Perhaps you can express that also simpler.

To retrieve also the Tag content:

```
urls = re.findall('<a .*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a>', page)
```

I really do not know what this second title does in your regex, perhaps you can also give an example text which does not match. Then I can give you a better answer why your regex does not work